# Resetting Chart Axis fails

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry for such a simple question, I can't figure this out. I have searched several forums for ideas but none of them solved my issue.

All I want is to have the graph axis reset upon the end of some code.

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 13").Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
```

This is what I used along with several variations and I get the same error.

> Method 'MinimumScaleIsAuto' of object 'Axis' failed.
>   **OR** Subscript out of Range

I can assure you that it is Chart 13, and on Sheet1.

Interestingly, if I record a macro doing what I want, then run the macro, I get the same error...

Comment: Sorry but, I ran this code and it works perfectly for a line chart.  You may want to add what type of chart you are using, maybe post a pic of the chart with the format axis shown.

Comment: Is it possible that your chart has the data in format that excel cannot process? That could happen if the numbers are being read as strings.

Comment: Interesting. I will update with a picture. I don't think I am doing anything funky, except maybe I am getting values from a formula rather than values themselves?